# Make an http request and parse the data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, httprequest

I am trying to make an http request to my backend server (run on java springboot) with my React-based frontnend, which returns a string that I want to parse and assign to values.  From what I have seen on the syntax pages, I want to believe that I am calling the request correctly.  My error message mentions "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')", which I think means that split() is not a valid operation for js or React?  Does anyone know what is the correct way to this?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Exchange from './Exchange'
import Recommendations from './Recommendations';
import axios from "axios";


function Middle(){
    const response = axios.get("http://localhost:8080/run");
    const data = response.data;
    const dataArr = data.split(",");
    
    return (

        <div className = 'Middle'>
            <h1>{data}</h1>
           <Exchange name = "Coinbase" btcBuy = {dataArr[1]} btcSell = "" ethBuy = "" ethSell = ""/>
           <Exchange name = "Binance" btcBuy = "" btcSell = "" ethBuy = "" ethSell = ""/>
           <Recommendations/>
        </div>

    );
};
export default Middle;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Also note that you need to wrap in useEffect and update state with useState per the upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the `data` variable is not a string. Also you need to use useEffect if you want to fetch data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Middle(){

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

      (async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/run");
          const data = response.data;
          setData(data); // use split if you have to, I dont think you need that.
        } catch(err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      })()

    }, [])
```

Comment: Note that this will fetch the data again on every single render. You might want to add a dependency array to `useEffect`

Comment: When I do this, I get a bunch of compilation errors saying that data, setData, and useState are not defined.  Do I need to import anything else? I dont believe I have to

Comment: oh... import useState and React aswell. Let me edit it.

Comment: i also forgot const [data, setData].

Comment: Thank you!  I believe this works, just right now I am getting the error message on my webpage console "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/run' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."  This seems to be a relatively common issue so I'll work on it a little bit first.

Comment: That is a server problem. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you do not read the `response` properly, as it is an asynchronous operation and your response is `undefined` at the time you make operations on it sequentially.

You have to place your code in the body of `.then`, like this:

```
let dataArr = [];
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/run")
    .then(response => {
        const data = response.data;
        dataArr = data.split(",");
    });
```

Comment: You can't do arbitrary side-effects (like an axios request) in a React function component. See the other answers.

Comment: So he can split that into multiple functions, my answer was only to give a sense of `async`ivity..

Comment: Except that the OP is clearly an inexperienced dev, and is going to copy-paste your answer into their React function component, and then not understand why it doesn't work or works but only once in awhile.